# Need select all classes inside a tag

Tags: jquery

My problem is that I need to hide just the classes inside a div on a click event. Right now my code looks like this.

```
<section>
   <h2>Section Title</h2>
   <div class="inner_wrapper">content</div>
   <div class="inner_wrapper">content</div>
   <div class="inner_wrapper">content</div>
</section>

<section>
   <h2>Section 2 Title</h2>
   <div class="inner_wrapper">content</div>
   <div class="inner_wrapper">content</div>
   <div class="inner_wrapper">content</div>
</section>
```

and so on. When I click an h2 I want to hide just the inner_wrapper divs that are inside that same section.

Comment: `siblings` will select all `.inner_wrapper` elements at the same level as the h2 before *OR* after. While this is probably fine, be aware there also is a `nextAll` and a `prevAll` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("h2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".inner_wrapper").hide();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VLRNX/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.inner_wrapper').hide();
});
```

If you're interested in re-displaying the content if the h2 is clicked again, you can do the following:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.inner_wrapper').toggle();
});
```